# &#8211 is not getting decoded properly in android

Tags: java, android, decoder

So I went through other similar post and used the decoder like this

```
excerptData = URLDecoder.decode(excerptData, "UTF-8");
excerptData = excerptData.replaceAll( "[\\u202C\\u202A]", "" );
_post.Excerpt = (Html.fromHtml(excerptData));
```

But #8211 and #8217 is not getting decoded to '-'. Am i missing here something.
Help would appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those seem like HTML entities.

Comment: Yeah I tried this Html.fromHtml(Html.escapeHtml((String) excerptData).toString()); But I didnt work either

Comment: Fixed it. Html.fromHtml(html.fromhtml(excerptData).Tostring());